# Different sessions show different streaming data with a single bokeh server, how to solve it?

Tags: windows-10, bokeh, python-3.7

I'm working on a simulated osilloscope where the server PC collects data and ultimately will publish the streaming plot online. Below is a working script that can do the job. However, when I open multiple browsers, the streaming plots exhibit different data. (Although they are using the same data source). The example 'ohlc' seems to have the same problem. So, what is the right way to do this? I'm considering to write data to a file, but that will bring some issues like file i/o delay and disk storage limitation etc. Thank you for any help.

[image]
[image]

```
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from functools import partial
import time


# this will be replaced with the real data collector in the end
def f_emitter(p=0.1):
    v = np.random.rand()
    return (dt.datetime.now(), 0. if v>p else v)


def make_document(doc, functions, labels):
    def update():
        for index, func in enumerate(functions):
            data = func()
            sources[index].stream(new_data=dict(time=[data[0]], data=[data[1]]), rollover=1000)
            annotations[index].text = f'{data[1]: .3f}'

    sources = [ColumnDataSource(dict(time=[], data=[])) for _ in range(len(functions))]
    figs = []
    annotations = []
    for i in range(len(functions)):
        figs.append(figure(x_axis_type='datetime',
                           y_axis_label=labels[i], toolbar_location=None,
                           active_drag=None, active_scroll=None))
        figs[i].line(x='time', y='data', source=sources[i])
        annotations.append(Label(x=10, y=10, text='', text_font_size='40px', text_color='black',
                                 x_units='screen', y_units='screen', background_fill_color='white'))
        figs[i].add_layout(annotations[i])
        # print(figs[i].plot_height)

    doc.add_root(column([fig for fig in figs], sizing_mode='stretch_both'))
    doc.add_periodic_callback(callback=update, period_milliseconds=100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # list of functions and labels to feed into the scope
    functions = [f_emitter]
    labels = ['emitter']

    server = Server({'/': partial(make_document, functions=functions, labels=labels)})
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    try:
        server.io_loop.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('keyboard interruption')
```

Answer (score 2):

When you connect with a new client, by default Bokeh creates a new session. Each session has its own document, so the data source end up not being the same.

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed that. Do you have any suggestion to force them to show the same streaming data?

Comment: You can specify the `bokeh-session-id` query parameter, something like `http://localhost:5006/?bokeh-session-id=2`. But note that Bokeh is not intended for such usage right now, so you will likely see some issues. On my end, I see that `DataRange1d` stop updating on the second tab.